# i cant send mail codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, email

I can't send mail from codeigniter to yandex mail when i using this code:

```
$config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'smtp.yandex.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'blablabla@yandex.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'blablabla',
        'mailtype'  => 'html',
        'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1',
        'newline' => "\r\n"
    );
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->initialize($config);

    $msg = $this->messages($f2, $f3);

    $this->email->to($f1);

    $this->email->subject('Here is Subject');
    $this->email->message($msg);

    if($this->email->send()){
        echo "Masuk!";
    }else{
        echo "Gagal!";
    }
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

And the result always says:

> Gagal!Cannot send mail with no "From" header.

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot send mail with no "From" header.

You simply need to add a `From` address to your email, by calling

```
$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
```

or

```
$this->email->from('your@example.com');
```

---

Depending on the sending and receiving provider, that might get you in trouble though if you try and send the email under another `From` address, than the one you authenticated against the SMTP server with - it might get classified as spam then (or even rejected by the SMTP server right away) - so in this case here you should use `blablabla@yandex.com` as `From`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set a name and email as a sender. 
for example if you set different email and name for sender it shows in inbox mail (Gmail for example) as like below image [image: email preview]